# gawk for-loop performance issue

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

I have a performance issue with gawk 3.1.5 (Linux) related to the use of for-loop.

Run this code

```
BEGIN {
    TagOpen["Req"] = "<S:Envelope"
    TagClose["Req"] = "<\\/S:Envelope"
    TagOpen["Resp"] = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope"
    TagClose["Resp"]= "<\\/SOAP-ENV:Envelope"
}

{ if ( NR % 10000 == 0 ) print NR }

{
    for (i in TagOpen) {

        if ( match($0, TagOpen[i]) )  printf "Open  [%s]\n", i

        if ( match($0, TagClose[i]) ) printf "Close [%s]\n", i
    }
}
```

on a 800,000 lines text file takes:

```
real    0m56.84s
user    0m56.02s
sys     0m0.29s
```

Run the apparently identical

```
BEGIN {
    TagOpen["Req"]  = "<S:Envelope"
    TagClose["Req"] = "<\\/S:Envelope"
    TagOpen["Resp"] = "<SOAP-ENV:Envelope"
    TagClose["Resp"]= "<\\/SOAP-ENV:Envelope"
}

{ if ( NR % 10000 == 0 ) print NR }

{
    i="Req"

    if ( match($0, TagOpen[i]) )  printf "Open  [%s]\n", i
    if ( match($0, TagClose[i]) ) printf "Close [%s]\n", i
            i="Resp"
    if ( match($0, TagOpen[i]) )  printf "Open  [%s]\n", i
    if ( match($0, TagClose[i]) ) printf "Close [%s]\n", i
}
```

takes:

```
real    0m3.36s
user    0m3.23s
sys     0m0.21s
```

I can't believe what I'm seeing!

Any idea?

P.S. This doesn't appen with "legacy" awk on HP-UX

Comment: Do they both produce the same output? Have you tried adding a `print i` in the loop in the first script to see what values `i` is taking to make sure it's what you think?

Comment: could you try with " if (match($0, TagOpen[i]) != 0 ) ?? "

Comment: yes, i try also print i. It's 0 and 1 as i expected.

Comment: no change with an explicit test of match()

Comment: gawk 3.1.5 is [8 years old](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gawk.git/refs/tags) -- can you upgrade and test on a modern version?

Comment: In you question you mention HP-UX: is your [tag:linux] tag accurate?

Comment: I see, Gleen, but i can't. Could you try for me. 
At this point, I have essentially a "phylosophical" interest in the problem... I tried on HP-UX and i didn't see any difference between two version of awk code.

Comment: (Actually, [13 years old](https://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/gawk/gawk-stable/ChangeLog?revision=1.187&view=markup#l1722) -- GNU migrated gawk from CVS to git 8 years ago)

Comment: You appear to be parsing XML. I would recommend you use an XML parser instead of awk for this task.

Comment: Why would the output of adding `print i` in the loop show that `i` has the values `0` and `1` - it should be `Req` and `Resp` shouldn't it? Are you sure you're running the script shown in your question?

Comment: Sorry, Ed, you are rigth.  0 and 1 were in an older version.

Comment: So do you have a problem with the script in the question or not? If so, what does it output when you add `print i` in the loop?

Comment: btw - think about what you're doing in your comparisons: you're calling `match()` which takes a regexp as the 2nd parameter and passing it `"<\\/S:Envelope"` where you've double-escaped the forward slash to try to protect it from being treated as a regexp metacharacter. a) It's NOT a regexp metacharacter so you don't need to escape it, and b) even if it was, you're cutting yourself and then applying a bandaid instead of not cutting yourself - use `index()` instead of `match()` since you apparently really want to look for a string, not a regexp, and then you won't have to escape regexp chars.

Comment: The script works done. The issue is only about performance of the for-loop. But Ed is rigth, "/" is not special in regexp so, now i have removed the "\\". Anyway I need to match against a regexp, because i don't known the lengthg of the open tag and the version of gawk i'm using requires a double "\" to escape a special character (but in this case it was unnecessary). Thanks to all!

Comment: Last time - **what does it output when you add print i in the loop?** idk what you mean by `I need to match against a regexp, because i don't known the length of the open tag` - that sounds like you misunderstand the way string and regexp matching work as string length is irrelevant. Also wrt `the version of gawk i'm using requires a double "\" to escape..` - it's not about awk versions, its because you're using a string in a regexp context so it has to be parsed twice, once to convert the string to a regexp and then again to use it as that regexp, hence the need for double escapes.

Comment: I think at this point it's safe to assume that the script in the question is not the script the OP was actual running her timing on and she has now realized her mistake and moved on so we can close this question.

Comment: I agree the OP question is unclear, yet I would like to point out Gianluca is an Italian [male name](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/10756/how-to-politely-notify-in-an-online-conversation-that-i-am-a-woman)